# how to edit a file via Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to create a Dockerfile to setup my hadoop environment.
In one of the steps I need to add some lines to my bashrc file. This is what I am doing:

```
RUN wget http://apache.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/hadoop/common/current/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxvf hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz
RUN cp -R hadoop-2.7.2 /usr/local/hadoop
RUN cd /usr/local/hadoop
RUN cat << EOF >> ~/.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
EOF
RUN source ~/.bashrc
```

However I am getting the error below:

```
Step 10 : EXPORT
Unknown instruction: EXPORT
```

Any idea how can I edit my bashrc file?

**NOTE:**

I also tried:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
ENV HADOOP_INSTALL /usr/local/hadoop
ENV PATH $PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
ENV HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME $HADOOP_INSTALL
ENV HADOOP_COMMON_HOME $HADOOP_INSTALL
ENV HADOOP_HDFS_HOME $HADOOP_INSTALL
ENV YARN_HOME $HADOOP_INSTALL
ENV HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR $HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
ENV HADOOP_OPTS "-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

and

```
RUN echo $'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo $'export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

still no success

Answer (score 0):

Try Dockerfile multiline syntax with echo:

```
RUN echo $'this is\n\
a multiline\n\
string\n'\
>> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: didn't work, docker does not complain but I then do a docker run debian cat ~/.bashrc and the new lines are missing